# Using POST Retrofit Flutter Error. The receiving system is not in the correct format

Tags: flutter

I'm having a problem using retrofit post data to server.
The data sent is not in the correct format with the server side.
retrofit: ^2.0.1
retrofit_generator: ^2.0.0
dio: ^4.0.1

```
  var body = Map<String, dynamic>();
  .
  .
  .
  if (params.agentCountryId != null) {
      body["agent_address_attributes[1][country_id]"] =
          params.agentCountryId;
    }
    if (params.agentProvinceId != null) {
      body["agent_address_attributes[1][addr_province_id]"] =
          params.agentProvinceId;
    }
    if (params.agentDistrictId != null) {
      body["agent_address_attributes[1][addr_district_id]"] =
          params.agentDistrictId;
    }
    if (params.agentWardId != null) {
      body["agent_address_attributes[1][addr_ward_id]"] =
          params.agentWardId;
    }
    if (params.agentStreet != null) {
      body["agent_address_attributes[1][street1]"] =
          params.agentStreet;
    }
  @POST("${ApiConstant.agent}")
  @FormUrlEncoded()
  Future<BaseObjectResponse<AgentModel>> createAgent(
      @Part() File? avatar, @Body() Map<String, dynamic> map);
```

Backend need to return this format

[image]

I don't know where the problem is still, hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

i think  `body["agent_address_attributes[1][country_id]"]` can't return value.  please try body['agent_address_attributes']['addr_...']

Comment: I tried using your method but got error